# In Flutter How can I take file data from outside

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get data from outside?
I want to transfer files from phone storage to app.
but I couldn't find an example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried [file picker?](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)

Its usage seems simple:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}
```

Also, it has null safety support + a good rating on [pub.dev](http://pub.dev)

**EDIT.** One more example for you, here it comes:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
   
   print(file.name);
   print(file.bytes);
   print(file.size);
   print(file.extension);
   print(file.path);
} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but I can't  understand th example ?

Comment: how can I define the file. This packages usage doesn't working eithier I getting error

Comment: There, I edited my answer. Make sure you follow the installations steps shown in the package page, and you try this package in a separate project first, so that you get confident in its usage.